# docker compose command: Invalid interpolation format for "command" option in service

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose

In my docker compose I have the following command:

```
command: bash -c 'while [[ "$(curl --connect-timeout 2 -s -o /dev/null -w ''%{http_code}'' https://mock-server:4000/readiness)" != "200" ]]; do echo ..; sleep 5; done; echo backend is up; npm start'
```

which waits until mock-server is up then run the start command for backend:

```
  backend:
    build: 
        context: ./test
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: bash -c 'while [[ "$(curl --connect-timeout 2 -s -o /dev/null -w ''%{http_code}'' https://mock-server:4000/readiness)" != "200" ]]; do echo ..; sleep 5; done; echo backend is up; npm start'
    ports: 
      - "3015:3015"
    depends_on:
      - couchdb
      - redis
      - mock-server
    user: root
```

But I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Invalid interpolation format for "command" option in service "backend": "bash -c 'while [[ "$(curl --connect-timeout 2 -s -o /dev/null -w ''%{http_code}'' https://uds-mock-server:4000/readiness)" != "200" ]]; do echo ..; sleep 5; done; echo backend is up;; npm start'"
```

I cannot see what is wrong with my command.
any help is appreciated

Comment: I'd try to avoid something quite that long in a `docker-compose.yml` file.  Put it into a separate shell script and `COPY` it into your image; you shouldn't need to declare a `command:` at all.  (For bonus points, make the "wait for the other container" part into an entrypoint script and make `npm start` be the command part.)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need to escape the `$` with `$$`

```
command: bash -c 'while [[ "$(curl --connect-timeout 2 -s -o /dev/null -w ''%{http_code}'' https://mock-server:4000/readiness)" != "200" ]]; do echo ..; sleep 5; done; echo backend is up; npm start'


command: bash -c 'while [[ "$$(curl --connect-timeout 2 -s -o /dev/null -w ''%{http_code}'' https://mock-server:4000/readiness)" != "200" ]]; do echo ..; sleep 5; done; echo backend is up; npm start'
```

That should fix the [build problem](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4485)

Comment: Highly probably you need to update your `docker-compose` version: e.g. `python3 -m pip docker-compose==1.22.0`

Comment: The answer is right for me using `docker-compose version 1.29.2, build 5becea4c`, `Python 3.9.6` and `pip 21.0.1`.